# Why is select option in Angular show wrong value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, I have `userSettings` where I have `dafaultPreset` (which is the id) and I have a list of `user presets`. And I want to show the default preset in HTML select element, where user can change presets.

In `HTML` I have a select option like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="bg" id="" (change)="patchPreset($event)" 
 [ngModel]="userSettings?.defaultPreset">
  <option value="null" disabled>Select Preset</option>
  <option *ngFor="let preset of userPresets" value="{{preset.id}}">{{preset.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And in my `.ts` file, when I add new `preset` to user, I'm calling an API for getting all user `presets` and assign again like this: `this.userPresets = response;`.

In that moment the default value in HTML select element changes to the first element of `userPresets`, even if the `defaultPreset` id is not changed. When I refresh the page, then it works fine.

**Example**

```
userPresets = [{id:1, name:1}, {id:2, name:2}, {id:3, name:3}];

userSettings.defaultPreset = 2;
```

And it shows `2` in `HTML` select element. When I again call API to get all `presets` and assign to `userPresets`, then in select element it shows `1`.
Can somebody explain me where I'm wrong?

Comment: The problem is that when you first select, you reference the origin value of `userPresets`. When you apply `this.userPresets = response` you change the entire object reference - therefore none of the original selected elements are available anymore. If you want to keep the previous selection you need to add or update the previous `userPresets` rather than completely assign it to response.

Comment: seems to be working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kumeww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts